# Transfer InputStream to another Service (across process boundaries) with ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe() failes with "EBADF (Bad file number)"

Tags: android, pipe, android-service, ipc, android-binder

I want to "send" an InputStream from one Android Service to another service running within a different process by using [`ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#createPipe%28%29), a stream-to-stream copy thread and a ParcelFileDescriptor, representing the read side of the pipe, which is given to the other service with means of Binder IPC.

### Sending Code (Process A)

I want to send a given InputStream to the receiving service:

```
public sendInputStream() {
    InputStream is = ...; // that's the stream for process/service B
    ParcelFileDescriptor pdf = ParcelFileDescriptorUtil.pipeFrom(is);
    inputStreamService.inputStream(pdf);
}
```

The ParcelFileDescriptorUtil is a helper class, with a classic `java.io.` stream-to-stream copy Thread:

```
public class ParcelFileDescriptorUtil {

    public static ParcelFileDescriptor pipeFrom(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        ParcelFileDescriptor readSide = pipe[0];
        ParcelFileDescriptor writeSide = pipe[1];

        // start the transfer thread
        new TransferThread(inputStream, new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(writeSide)).start();

        return readSide;
    }

    static class TransferThread extends Thread {
        final InputStream mIn;
        final OutputStream mOut;

        TransferThread(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            super("ParcelFileDescriptor Transfer Thread");
            mIn = in;
            mOut = out;
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            try {
                while ((len = mIn.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    mOut.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                mOut.flush(); // just to be safe
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.e("TransferThread", e);
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    mIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                try {
                    mOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Receiving Service Code (Process B)

The receiving service's `.aidl`:

```
package org.exmaple;
interface IInputStreamService {
    void inputStream(in ParcelFileDescriptor pfd);
}
```

The receiving service, called by Process A:

```
public class InputStreamService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IInputStreamService.Stub mBinder = new IInputStreamService.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void inputStream(ParcelFileDescriptor pfd) throws RemoteException {

        InputStream is = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(pfd);
        OutputStream os = ...;
        int len;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // this catches the exception shown below
        }
    }
};
```

But `in.read()` in `inputStream()` always throws a `IOException`

```
java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:442)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
```

It seems like the EBADF errno is set by `read()` when the file descriptor is closed. But I don't know what is causing it and how to fix it.

And yes, I know that a ConentProvider would also be a possibility. But shouldn't it also work with my approach? Are there any other ways to hand an InputStream stream to a different service in Android?

<sup>On a side note: CommonsWare created a similar [project using a ContentProvider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ContentProvider/Pipe/src/com/commonsware/android/cp/pipe/PipeProvider.java) (related SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920429/anyone-have-mediaplayer-working-with-parcelfiledescriptor-and-createpipe), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894976/anyone-have-mediarecorder-working-with-parcelfiledescriptor-and-createpipe)). It's where I got most of the ideas for my approach from</sup>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like the cause was the `ParcelFileDescriptor` being an argument of the service method.  If the service does *return* the `ParcelFileDescriptor` it works as expected.

### Sending Service (Process A)

```
public void sendInputStream() {
    InputStream is = ...; // that's the stream for process/service B
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = inputStreamService.inputStream();
    OutputStream os = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pfd);

    int len;
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
            os.write(buf, 0, len);
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try { is.close(); } catch (IOException e1) {}
        try { os.close(); } catch (IOException e1) {}
    }
}
```

### Receiving Service Code (Process B)

The receiving service's `.aidl`:

```
package org.exmaple;
interface IInputStreamService {
    ParcelFileDescriptor inputStream();
}
```

The receiving service, called by Process A:

```
public class InputStreamService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IInputStreamService.Stub mBinder = new IInputStreamService.Stub() {

    @Override
    public void ParcelFileDescriptor inputStream() throws RemoteException {
                // one can read the contents of the Processes A's InputStream
                // from the following OutputStream
                OutputStream os = ...;
                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptorUtil.pipeTo(os);
                return pfd;
    }
};
```

The ParcelFileDescriptorUtil is a helper class, with a classic `java.io.` stream-to-stream copy Thread. *Now we have to use the `pipeTo()` method*.

```
public class ParcelFileDescriptorUtil {

    public static ParcelFileDescriptor pipeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
        ParcelFileDescriptor readSide = pipe[0];
        ParcelFileDescriptor writeSide = pipe[1];

        // start the transfer thread
        new TransferThread(new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(readSide), outputStream).start();

        return writeSide;
    }

    static class TransferThread extends Thread {
        final InputStream mIn;
        final OutputStream mOut;

        TransferThread(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
            super("ParcelFileDescriptor Transfer Thread");
            mIn = in;
            mOut = out;
            setDaemon(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;

            try {
                while ((len = mIn.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    mOut.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                mOut.flush(); // just to be safe
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.e("TransferThread", e);
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    mIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                try {
                    mOut.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to transfer InputStreams across process boundaries, one drawback is that there is some CPU time involved in the stream-to-stream copies.