# Passing large files on the fly between Android processes securely

Tags: android, sockets, pipe, android-contentprovider, named-pipes

```
  SourceNode --|                                  |--> StorageLocation     (remote)
               |--> MyService <-ipc-> CallerApp --|                        (Android)
```

`MyService` and `CallerApp` are inside the phone; StorageLocation may be inside the phone or yet another remote node outside the phone. The scenario is the following:

1. CallerApp tells an Android service via AIDL to fetch file X; file X is very large.
2. MyService is connected to a remote SourceNode and starts receiving X from that remote node.
3. Now while MyService is receiving X from SourceNode, it needs to pass the bytes read to CallerApp while doing the reading.
4. Conclusion: the data is going all the way from SourceNode on the left, to StorageLocation on the right, while using the phone as a proxy. MyService and CallerApp are different processes.

**The problem here is on how to do IPC between MyService and CallerApp efficiently.** In some cases, file X will be saved locally on the private storage of CallerApp. In other cases, file X will be sent to a remote storage location and the phone is in a way working as a proxy for the transfer. You can think of StorageLocation as either the local phone storage or as a remote cloud provider.

- I tried following an approach similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18232196/3715151) using a `pipe pair` and a `transfer thread` but I'm getting speeds of just over 5 KB/second on a high-end phone to transfer data between MyService and CallerApp. This is just too slow if transferring hundreds of MB.
- I'm considering using a `ContentProvider`, but from my understanding file X would have to be first saved into MyService and only then would CallerApp be able to use it. File X cannot be first saved into MyService and then passed into CallerApp because it may be so large that it won't even fit into the available storage space (in this case the phone would just be a proxy for the data).
- Haven't tried `local sockets` but if a pipe pair is slow I don't know if it would be any better.

---

Any insight on how this may be solvable, i.e. transfer large amounts of data between MyService and CallerApp efficiently?

(Also, can I write directly from MyService into the private storage location of CallerApp *without* using a pipe pair as an intermediary, i.e. MyService would read from SourceNode socket and write to an OutputStream handle of a file created in CallerApp?)

Comment: "This is just too slow if transferring hundreds of MB" -- and when you did a performance analysis, using tools like Traceview, to determine precisely where you are spending your time, what did you learn?

Comment: @CommonsWare I learned that it is a bad idea to concatenate ten thousand strings in Java. Oh, the shame of it all!

Comment: "I learned that it is a bad idea to concatenate ten thousand strings in Java" -- yeah, that'll sting a little. I haven't served a huge file from Java via `ParcelFileDescriptor`, only smaller things. However, serving stuff that way is how `MediaStore` serves videos to video player apps, and so it *should* have a reasonable data transfer rate. Note, though, that I'd strong recommend using a `ContentProvider` and `openFile()` over the pass-the-`ParcelFileDescriptor` approach, just to ensure timing is handled well.