# Stream file from my cloud app to 3rd party app (handle read/write byte[] requests) in Android

Tags: android, file, streaming, fileprovider, android-document-provider

I want to stream my files directly from my cloud app to 3rd party apps, **without downloading the file in advance** on non-rooted device.

For example: When I create an Intent to open an audio file from my Cloud app **with any 3rd party audio player**, the player may not need to read() the whole file, but only specific range of bytes[] from the file, which are played in the specific seconds (streaming). So I want to provide a virtual file to the 3rd party player app and when the player starts reading the chunks of the file, the read(byte[], offset, count) requests to be send to my cloud app with the requested range of bytes, so my app to be able to return these chunks of bytes[] (I have the opportunity to return only specific byte range of the file from my cloud server).

I try to use DocumentProvider and FileProvider, but when openDocument(..)/openFile(..) is called from the 3rd party app, my app can **return only ParcelFileDescryptor for a file, which is downloaded already**. I can`t return my own FileInputStream object, from which I can return the requested bytes[] from the 3rd party app with read() requests.

Is there any way to provide (stream) a file to 3rd party app and the read(byte[], offset, count) requests to be redirected to my cloud app, and my app return the specific bytes to the 3rd party app?

My code from the openDocument() method in DocumentProvider:

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openDocument(final String documentId, final String mode,
                                         CancellationSignal signal)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    final File file = getFileForDocId(documentId);
    final int accessMode = ParcelFileDescriptor.parseMode(mode);
    final boolean isWrite = (mode.indexOf('w') != -1);

    if (isWrite) {
        // Attach a close listener if the document is opened in write mode.
        try {
            Handler handler = new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper());
            return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, accessMode, handler,
                    new ParcelFileDescriptor.OnCloseListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClose(IOException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "A file with id " + documentId + " has been closed!  Time to " +
                                    "update the server.");
                        }

                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } else {
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, accessMode);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to stream my files directly from my cloud app` Extend ContentProvider. No intermediate storage needed.

Comment: And read about -not possible- ramdom access in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637629/can-we-install-an-apk-from-a-contentprovider. (but i did not check that)

Comment: How can I attach to the read/write requests from the other 3rd party app if I extend ContentProvider? Can you give me an example code?

Comment: Hmmm. Streaming is reading only for me. I  only experimented with reading  using ContentProvider for files not from local storage.

Comment: Can you give me code example only for reading, please?

Comment: When i experimented with the openFile() function extending ContentProvider i used code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212152/transfer-inputstream-to-another-service-across-process-boundaries-with-parcelf but never got it really done. I ended up first downloding the file to storage and then opening it from there. Piping is the word.

Comment: One of the problems is that receiving data from internet needs to be done in a thread. I supplied the provider with a thread and used a Thread.join() but maybe its not needed when de consumer uses a thread. (As is advised doing I/O).

Comment: https://github.com/google/samba-documents-provider/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/sambadocumentsprovider/provider/SambaDocumentsProvider.java